# MAAS Distributed setup issues

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, maas

Consider this scenario: [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDYfS.jpg)

MAAS Region Controller:

- In AWS, IP Range 10.8.0.0/16
- Ubuntu 20.04
- MAAS 3.2, Snap installation

MAAS Rack Controller 1:

- In Office 1, IP Range 10.9.100.0/24
- Ubuntu 20.04
- MAAS 3.2, Snap installation

MAAS Rack Controller 2:

- In Office 2, IP Range 10.6.200.0/24
- Ubuntu 20.04
- MAAS 3.2, Snap installation

I am able to register both rack controllers with the region controller in AWS and configure DHCP on both subnets in the region controller. When I boot a computer in PXE, it talks to rack controller as I can see the IP address of the rack controller on the console when it fires up. However, after sometime of PXE booting, the enlisting fails with message:

```
cloud-init[1724]: Can not apply stage final, no datasource found! Likely bad things to come!
```

I also saw another message during PXE boot where it seems to be hitting the network address instead of the region or rack controller address when looking for datasources.

```
cloud-init[1092]: 2022-07-14 17:46:46,785 url_helper.py [ERROR]: Timed out, no response from urls: ['http://10-9-100-0--24.maas-internal:5248/MAAS/2012-03-01/meta-data/instance-id']
```

My gut says it has something to do with NAT but I can't figure out where exactly or what exactly is wrong here.

Has anyone run into similar issues while implementing MAAS distributed setup? Any help here is highly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong with my setup.

I needed to edit

> /etc/maas/preseeds/enlist

with the following information:

```
#cloud-config
datasource:
  MAAS:
    timeout : 50
    max_wait : 120
    # there are no default values for metadata_url or oauth credentials
    # If no credentials are present, non-authed attempts will be made.
    metadata_url: http://<region_controller_ip>:5240/MAAS/metadata
```

Hopefully, this will help someone in a similar situation!